# What is difference between CROSS APPLY and LATERAL in oracle?

Tags: oracle

I am able to understand the difference between Cross apply and Outer apply.
But what is the difference between Cross apply and Lateral?
Both seem to correlate an inline view and join the left table with the right table.

Comment: `lateral` is standard ANSI SQL, `cross apply` was added to be compatible with SQL Server's non-standard implementation of lateral joins

Comment: You mean to say both are the same and are present to support different standards.

Comment: Yes (although `cross apply` is not a "standard" at all - it's just the dialect Microsoft chose)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Is that so? Or did you get them mixed up? `lateral` uses the comma syntax for the lateral join, and uses the Oracle proprietary `(+)` notation for the equivalent of `outer apply`. I don't have access to the ANSI standard, but I would have expected just the opposite - that `cross apply` and `outer apply` are the ANSI standard syntax, and `lateral` (possibly with the `(+)` notation) the old-style, Oracle proprietary syntax.

Comment: @AmanSinghRajpoot - there are some small differences. `lateral` is used as an equivalent of both `cross apply` and `outer apply` - depending on whether you use the `(+)` notation (following the lateral view definition). This is entirely similar to the difference between Oracle notation for joins (inner or outer joins) and the `inner join` and `outer join` syntax mandated in the SQL Standard: the Oracle notation is the equivalent of both inner and outer joins.

Comment: @mathguy: no, `lateral` does not "use" (or require) the ancient comma joins: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7bbfb2c6aa312ebc8dc1fe92be353595 `lateral` **is** the ANSI syntax (e.g. also supported by PostgreSQL)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - cool, glad I asked. I learned something I didn't know - the ANSI join syntax with `LATERAL`. I had only seen `LATERAL` used with comma in the `FROM` clause, and with the `(+)` operator for outer joins. Good to know! I had fallen in the habit of using `CROSS APPLY` and `OUTER APPLY` thinking they are the ANSI syntax; much better to use `INNER JOIN LATERAL` and `OUTER JOIN LATERAL` then!

Comment: @mathguy, I did get the chance to study but today I read about Oracle proprietary join syntax. So from all this discussion, I understand that Cross apply and Outer apply were added to be compatible with SQL Server's non_standard implementation. Lateral is ANSI join syntax and can be used with Inner join, right outer join, and left outer join. The main reason to use Lateral is to correlate inline view with outer query. So ANSI syntax should always be preferred?

Comment: There are still some things I don't know or understand, or perhaps there are some things that don't quite work with the ANSI `lateral` syntax. For example, if I have a table with column `id` (PK) and `str` (either XML or JSON, etc.) I can do a lateral join to something like `json_table`, either with the comma notation or with `cross apply` or `outer apply`. I don't know how that works with the ANSI `lateral` join syntax (if at all).

Answer (score 0):

It's not a general answer. It's only an example of something you can do with lateral but not with apply:

you have a table t (has only 1 lines in this example). For each line of t, you make 2 differents types of computations (X and Y) which returns severals (3) lines.

you don't want to make a cross product of X and Y. You want that the first lines X to be next to the first line of Y and so on.

> | X | Y |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 11 |
> | 2 | 22 |
> | 3 | 33 |

If you use cross apply. the only  way (witout creating subqueries) to that is to add a condition (in the where block)

```
WITH
    t (X, Y)
    AS
        (SELECT json_array (1, 2, 3), json_array (11, 22, 33) FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (SELECT t1.idx, t1.x, t2.Y
           FROM t
                CROSS APPLY
                (SELECT *
                   FROM JSON_TABLE (
                            t.X,
                            '$'
                            COLUMNS (
                                NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                                    COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY, x PATH '$'))))
                t1
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    t.Y,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS (
                        NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                            COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY, y PATH '$'))) t2
          WHERE t1.idx = t2.idx)                            --on t1.idx=t2.idx
SELECT step2.x, step2.Y
  FROM step2;
```

But with lateral you can do that with a jointure. It easier to read.

```
 WITH
    t (X, Y)
    AS
        (SELECT json_array (1, 2, 3), json_array (11, 22, 33) FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (SELECT t1.idx, t1.x, t2.Y
           FROM t
                CROSS APPLY
                (SELECT *
                   FROM JSON_TABLE (
                            t.X,
                            '$'
                            COLUMNS (
                                NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                                    COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY, x PATH '$'))))
                t1
                INNER JOIN
                LATERAL (
                    SELECT *
                      FROM JSON_TABLE (
                               t.Y,
                               '$'
                               COLUMNS (
                                   NESTED PATH '$[*]'
                                       COLUMNS (idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                                                y PATH '$')))--where t1.idx=t2.idx
                                                             ) t2
                    ON t1.idx = t2.idx)
SELECT *
  FROM step2;
```

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3701f08be408ca397959c262a1491239)

[where the example comes from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72626168/oracle-json-sql-with-arrays-to-multi-field/72626643#72626643)