# Oracle json SQL with arrays to multi field

Tags: sql, oracle

here is json column in Oracle DB table.

**table name : test1**

| ITEM_ID | CAT1 | CAT2 | POS_VAL_JSON |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | {"X" : [1,2,3], "Y" : [1,2,3]} |

**table name : test2**

| ITEM_ID | CAT1 | CAT2 | X | Y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ITEM1 | A | 1 | {1,2,3} | {1,2,3} |

How can I get data like this from table1 and table2 each ?

| X | Y | ITEM_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | ITEM1 |
| 2 | 2 | ITEM1 |
| 3 | 3 | ITEM1 |

Comment: Post JSON data as text not image! Tag Oracle database.

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time i tried to post a question, now tables are shown

Comment: No problem, now show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: @sh_ted.yun in test2 are X,Y arrays ? you write {1,2,3} not [1,2,3]

Comment: miss typed sorry, they are array, [1,2,3], and what i've tried all failed. json table query. :(

Comment: SELECT re.item_id, jt.*
    FROM 
    
        test1 ,
        JSON_TABLE(test1.POS_VAL_JSON, '$' COLUMNS (
                                                        nested path '$.X[*]'
                                                        columns( x path '$'),
                                                        nested path '$.Y[*]'
                                                        columns( y path '$')
                                            )
        ) jt

Answer (score 0):

this code works for test2:

```
WITH
    test2 (ITEM_ID,
           cat1,
           cat2,
           X,
           Y)
    AS
        (SELECT 'item1',
                'A',
                1,
                json_array (1, 2, 3),
                json_array (1, 2, 3)
           FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (SELECT test2.item_id, t1.name X, ROWNUM num
           FROM test2
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test2.X,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS (name PATH '$'))) t1),
    step3
    AS
        (SELECT test2.item_id, t1.name Y, ROWNUM num
           FROM test2
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test2.X,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$[*]' COLUMNS (name PATH '$'))) t1)
SELECT step3.item_id, step3.Y, step2.X
  FROM step3 JOIN step2 ON step2.num = step3.num
```

this code works for test1

```
WITH
    test1 (ITEM_ID,
           cat1,
           cat2,
           pos_val_json)
    AS
        (SELECT 'item1',
                'A',
                1,
                json_object ('X' VALUE json_array (1, 2, 3),
                             'Y' VALUE json_array (1, 2, 3))
           FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (SELECT test1.item_id, t1.*,rownum num
           FROM test1
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test1.pos_val_json,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$.X[*]' COLUMNS (X PATH '$'))) t1
                    
                    
) ,step3 as (SELECT test1.item_id, t2.*,rownum num
           FROM test1
           CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test1.pos_val_json,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS (NESTED PATH '$.Y[*]' COLUMNS (Y PATH '$'))) t2)
SELECT step3.item_id,step3.Y,step2.X
  FROM step3 join step2 on step2.num=step3.num
```

> | X | Y | ITEM_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | ITEM1 |
> | 2 | 2 | ITEM1 |
> | 3 | 3 | ITEM1 |

this code works for test1 only if the array has 3 values

```
WITH
    test1 (ITEM_ID,
           cat1,
           cat2,
           pos_val_json)
    AS
        (SELECT 'item1',
                'A',
                1,
                json_object ('X' VALUE json_array (1, 2, 3),
                             'Y' VALUE json_array (1, 2, 3))
           FROM DUAL),
    test2 (ITEM_ID,
           cat1,
           cat2,
           X,
           Y)
    AS
        (SELECT 'item1',
                'A',
                1,
                json_array (1, 2, 3),
                json_array (1, 2, 3)
           FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (SELECT test1.item_id,
                t.*
           FROM test1
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test1.pos_val_json,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS ("X0" PATH '$.X[0]',
                             "X1" PATH '$.X[1]',
                             "X2" PATH '$.X[2]',
                             "Y0" PATH '$.Y[0]',
                             "Y1" PATH '$.Y[1]',
                             "Y2" PATH '$.Y[2]'
                             )) t),
step3 as( SELECT *
  FROM step2
   unpivot(
                (x_value,y_value)
                for xy_name
                in ((x0,y0) as 'xy_0',
                (x1,y1) as 'xy_1',
                (x2,y2) as 'xy_2')
             )
             )
             select item_id,X_value as x, y_value as y from step3
```

this code works for test2 only if the array has 3 values

```
WITH
    test2 (ITEM_ID,
           cat1,
           cat2,
           X,
           Y)
    AS
        (SELECT 'item1',
                'A',
                1,
                json_array (1, 2, 3),
                json_array (1, 2, 3)
           FROM DUAL),
    step2
    AS
        (
      SELECT test2.item_id,
                t1.*,t2.*
           FROM test2
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test2.X,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS ("X0" PATH '$[0]',
                             "X1" PATH '$[1]',
                             "X2" PATH '$[2]'
                             )) t1
                             
                CROSS APPLY
                JSON_TABLE (
                    test2.Y,
                    '$'
                    COLUMNS ("Y0" PATH '$[0]',
                             "Y1" PATH '$[1]',
                             "Y2" PATH '$[2]'
                             )) t2) , --select * from step2
step3 as( SELECT *
  FROM step2
   unpivot(
                (x_value,y_value)
                for xy_name
                in ((x0,y0) as 'xy_0',
                (x1,y1) as 'xy_1',
                (x2,y2) as 'xy_2')
             )
             )
             select item_id,X_value as x, y_value as y from step3
```

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=6efa41401d5792f3b2a3c668fc80c053)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but length of arrays can be far longger than this example. but all arrays will have same lenghth.  Your suggestion can be to long with large arrays..

Comment: @sg_ted.yun Ok. In fact that is simplier if you consider that . (see the first 2 solutions). I will perhaps delete the 2 last solutions because it is working only for a particular case. Unless you have any objections

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON_TABLE` to get the `X` values with `FOR ORDINALITY` to get an index and then the same for the `Y` values and join:

```sql
SELECT x, y, item_id
FROM   test1 t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT idx, x
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.pos_val_json,
                  '$.X[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                    x   NUMBER PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) x
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT idx, y
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.pos_val_json,
                  '$.Y[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                    y   NUMBER PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) y
       ON (x.idx = y.idx)
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE test1 (
  ITEM_ID      VARCHAR2(20),
  CAT1         VARCHAR2(20),
  CAT2         NUMBER,
  POS_VAL_JSON CLOB CHECK (POS_VAL_JSON IS JSON)
);

INSERT INTO test1 (ITEM_ID, CAT1, CAT2, POS_VAL_JSON)
VALUES ('ITEM1', 'A', 1, '{"X" : [1,2,3], "Y" : [1,2,3]}');
```

Outputs:

> | X | Y | ITEM_ID |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 1 | ITEM1 |
> | 2 | 2 | ITEM1 |
> | 3 | 3 | ITEM1 |

---

Similarly, for `test2` you can use:

```sql
SELECT x.x, y.y, t.item_id
FROM   test2 t
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT idx, x
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.X,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                    x   NUMBER PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) x
       INNER JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT idx, y
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.Y,
                  '$[*]'
                  COLUMNS (
                    idx FOR ORDINALITY,
                    y   NUMBER PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) y
       ON (x.idx = y.idx)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8f9719da7edd3ff3e99bc9d48e1d2c1f)*